# Super+[Number] to hide an application as well as activate it

Tags: gnome, 22.04, shortcut-keys, window-manager

I'm using GNOME 42.9 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and want to replicate a specific Windows feature. In Windows, pressing Win+[number] minimizes or unhides the window of a specific application pinned to the taskbar. I want to achieve the same functionality with the Super+[number] keys in my Ubuntu setup.

Specifically, I want Super+[number] to:

- Activate the application if it's currently not visible (whether through unhiding or starting)
- Hide it if it's currently visible.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+# seems to be treated by the Ubuntu dock the same way as a mouse-click on the icon. Mouse-clicks are controlled by a key in GSettings - specifically, `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action`.

To see all the ways that you can set that value, you can run the following command at the Terminal:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

There may be multiple options listed that include minimizing when a dock icon is selected - you can choose among them, but the straight-up minimize behavior can be obtained by running:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Changing it to `focus-minimize-or-previews` got the desired behavior! Please feel free to add this to your answer, if you like. I used `dconf-editor` for what it's worth.